# Celery task is still gettng exectued even though I'm raising an exception on task_prerun

Tags: celery, fastapi, celery-task

I need to perform some basic verifications on celery tasks before they are executed. I need to perform this verification when the task is assigned to a worker because I need to check if the worker has enough memory to perform the task. I'm doing this verification using the task_prerun method:

```
@task_prerun.connect
def task_previous_check(sender=None, task=None, **kwargs):
    
    # Get the amount required by the task
    needed_amount = task.request.args[0][-1]

    amount_allowed = 10

    #Check if there's enough
    if needed_measure > amount_allowed:
        
        # Stop the task from being executed
        raise Exception("Insufficient amount to accept the task")

    else:
        #Proceed with the task if there is enough
        return
```

However, when this verification is supposed to raise an exception and stop it from being executed, it raises the exception but it still executes the task. Should I be doing this differently ?

I've tried using the task_prerun method and raising an exception. Aditionally, I also tried using the task.retry method and, even though it does retry to execute the task, it still executes the task that time.